# Find and remove multiple rows based on values in CSV Excel

Tags: excel, replace, vba

Is there any way of deleting all rows that contain a certain value from another workbook? For example, I want to remove the rows that contain:

123@abc.com

234@def.com

567@hlk.com

890@kiv.com ... and so on

There are 5000 emails that need to be removed. Tried a traditional Find and Replace, this would take a while though. Any ideas?

EDIT: The CSV I am finding the values from has no extraneous data in it, so I can in theory select everything in that CSV as a find value.

Comment: does it have to be VBA? If it's a one off, you can use `vlookup` and sort to find the error fields, then delete

Comment: Apply Data > Filter to the column. Then use the filter to deselect the irrelevant values. That will hide all the addresses you don't want. If you really need a list with those values removed rather than just hidden, then the final step is simply to copy the filtered list and paste values to somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub test()
' build a list of the values\strings to search for and count how many items are in the list
  check_list = "123@abc, 234@def, 567@hlk, 890@kiv"
  list_count = 4

' determine how many rows to check and assign to a variable
  numbs_rows = whatever you determine

' step through the rows and check for a match using "instr"; if there is a match, delete the row
  Range("A1").select    ' or where ever you want to start
  for x = 1 to list_count
     srch_trm = application.choose(x, check_list)  
     for y = 1 to numb_rows      
        if instr(1, activecell, srch_trm, vbTextCompare) > 1 then
           Selection.EntireRow.Delete
        end if
        activecell.offset(1,0).select
     next 
  next
End Sub
```

Comment: Where is this put? I'm in the Visual Basic area, bit lost now though. Thanks!

Comment: Create \ insert a module in the VBA Project for your workbook